Group uniqueness wrt generating set of the Cayley graph
Given a valid Cayley graph without specified generating set (so the edge labels just enumerate abstract group elements $a, b, \ldots$ and vertices are not labeled) is the group defined by such graph unique?
I am mainly interested in finite groups.

Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about how to ask a good question.

Consider the free group $G_1:= \mathbb{F}_2$ generated by a set $S$ with two elements. The Cayley graph of $G_1$ with generating set $S$ is a $4$-regular tree, but with edges oriented in a specific way.
Consider the free product $G_2$ of four copies of $\mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z}$, and take the canonical generating set. The Cayley graph of $G_2$ is a $4$-regular tree… but it might have double edges, depending on the precise definition of the Cayley graph.
And, of course, $G_1$ and $G_2$ are not isomorphic.
There are other examples in the comments of this question. For example, the cyclic group of order $4$ with generating set given by a generator and its inverse, and the direct product of two cyclic groups of order two with generating set given by the union of the unique generating sets of the factors are isomorphic, as unlabeled graphs. It’s even worse if you allow non-minimal generating sets: the Cayley graph of any finite group with the whole group as the generating set is the complete graph.

Thank you so much! I am not sure if I am missing something trivial here but is the answer for finite groups a yes (upto isomorphisms)?

This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the meta announcement regarding quality standards.
